# implement kotlin module with java application produce java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of resource classes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multidex, clean-architecture

I am currently trying to migrate project written in single module to feature-module-clean-architecture.
Here I've written multiple modules in kotlin which have been working for another project as well which works fine in that project.
But when I come to implement this module in the project I am getting this annoying error:

this got removed after adding static string instead of getting from resource

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: L........../R$string;
```

still it have problem

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: L........../R$layout;
```

please find the complete trace below:

```
2020-07-08 00:03:21.895 16927-16927/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nitv.prabhutv.movies, PID: 16927
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sadip/featureauth/R$layout;
        at com.sadip.featureauth.ui.auth.AuthFragment.layoutId(AuthFragment.kt:62)
        at sadip.base.basesetup.platform.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:64)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6691)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sadip.featureauth.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nitv.prabhutv.movies-Rln9LCYsxpN-Eb3aj__UGw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nitv.prabhutv.movies-Rln9LCYsxpN-Eb3aj__UGw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.nitv.prabhutv.movies-Rln9LCYsxpN-Eb3aj__UGw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.sadip.featureauth.ui.auth.AuthFragment.layoutId(AuthFragment.kt:62) 
        at sadip.base.basesetup.platform.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:64) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6691) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Note: multidex is enabled, application extends multidexApplication, heap size is large 4g, dexoption is jumbo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big and really misleading error log of android. The problem was with the library version on Realm used in main gradle file of project. It got solved after just updating the library version.